# Using DataGridViewAutoFilter with Equin BindingListView

Tags: c#, datagridview, bindinglist

I'm attempting to use DataGridViewAutoFilter with my DataGridView, but in order to do so, I need a data source that implements IBindingListView. In order to do that, I'm using Equin.ApplicationFramework BindingListView which, as far as I can tell, doesn't support string filters since it keeps throwing the exception:

> 'Cannot set filter from string expression.'

I'm guessing AutoFilter wants to use string expressions to filter the list, but that BindingListView from Equin doesn't support that option.

Does anyone know how to get DataGridViewAutoFilter to work with a List?

My binding list is defined as follows:

```
BindingListView<ScoutingRecord> displayedData = new BindingListView<ScoutingRecord>(Current.data);
```

I'm applying the AutoFilter headers as follows:

```
    private void dgvMain_BindingContextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (dgvMain.DataSource == null) return;

        foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in dgvMain.Columns)
        {
            col.HeaderCell = new DataGridViewAutoFilterColumnHeaderCell(col.HeaderCell);
        }
        dgvMain.AutoResizeColumns();
    }
```

And the ScoutingRecord class is defined as follows:

```
   public class ScoutingRecord
    {
        public string TeamNumber { get; set; }
        public string MatchNumber { get; set; }
        public string Alliance { get; set; }
        public string Position { get; set; }
     }
```

Is there a different BindingList implementation I should be using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was never able to get the Equin implementation to work, but after doing some research and using a number of examples from different MSDN blog entries I was able to create an AdvancedList class that supports filtering. At the moment, it only supports one filter at a time, but I'm working on expanding it with multiple filters.

I'm surprised, however, that there isn't a standard implementation available within .NET. My aggregate AdvancedList class is included below.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Reflection;

namespace AdvancedList
{
    public class AdvancedList<T> : BindingList<T>, IBindingListView where T : class
    {
        private bool isSorted;
        private ListSortDirection sortDirection = ListSortDirection.Ascending;
        private PropertyDescriptor sortProperty;

        private string filterValue = null;
        private string filterPropertyNameValue;
        private Object filterCompareValue;

        private string[] filterPropertyNameValues;
        private Object[] filterCompareValues;

        List<T> unfilteredListValue = new List<T>();

        // Gets the property that indicates which property we're filtering against.
        public string FilterPropertyName
        {
            get { return filterPropertyNameValue; }
        }

        // Gets the property indicating the value we're comparing the property to.
        public Object FilterCompare
        {
            get { return filterCompareValue; }
        }

        // Create a blank instance of AdvancedList
        public AdvancedList()
        {
        }

        // Populate the list from a source list
        public AdvancedList(List<T> list) : base(list)
        {
        }

        // Gets the property that indicates if sorting is supported
        protected override bool SupportsSortingCore
        {
            get { return true; }
        }

        // Gets the property that indicates if the list is sorted
        protected override bool IsSortedCore
        {
            get { return isSorted; }
        }

        // Gets the proerty indicating the sort direction
        protected override ListSortDirection SortDirectionCore
        {
            get { return sortDirection; }
        }

        // Gets the property descriptor used for sorting the list
        protected override PropertyDescriptor SortPropertyCore
        {
            get { return sortProperty; }
        }

        // Removes any sorting applied
        protected override void RemoveSortCore()
        {
            sortDirection = ListSortDirection.Ascending;
            sortProperty = null;
            isSorted = false;
        }

        // Enables a sorting of the list
        protected override void ApplySortCore(PropertyDescriptor prop, ListSortDirection direction)
        {
            sortProperty = prop;
            sortDirection = direction;

            List<T> list = Items as List<T>;
            if (list == null) return;

            list.Sort(Compare);

            isSorted = true;
            //fire an event that the list has been changed.
            OnListChanged(new ListChangedEventArgs(ListChangedType.Reset, -1));
        }

        // Compare the values
        private int Compare(T lhs, T rhs)
        {
            var result = OnComparison(lhs, rhs);
            //invert if descending
            if (sortDirection == ListSortDirection.Descending)
                result = -result;
            return result;
        }

        // Handle different compare instances.
        private int OnComparison(T lhs, T rhs)
        {
            object lhsValue = lhs == null ? null : sortProperty.GetValue(lhs);
            object rhsValue = rhs == null ? null : sortProperty.GetValue(rhs);
            if (lhsValue == null)
            {
                return (rhsValue == null) ? 0 : -1; //nulls are equal
            }
            if (rhsValue == null)
            {
                return 1; //first has value, second doesn't
            }
            if (lhsValue is IComparable)
            {
                return ((IComparable)lhsValue).CompareTo(rhsValue);
            }
            if (lhsValue.Equals(rhsValue))
            {
                return 0; //both are the same
            }
            //not comparable, compare ToString
            return lhsValue.ToString().CompareTo(rhsValue.ToString());
        }

        public void ApplySort(ListSortDescriptionCollection sorts)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        // Return true to indicate this class supports filtering
        public bool SupportsFiltering
        {
            get { return true; }
        }

        // Return the unfiltered list.
        public List<T> UnfilteredList
        {
            get { return unfilteredListValue; }
        }

        // Get and Set te filter string
        public string Filter
        {
            get
            {
                return filterValue;
            }

            set
            {
                if (filterValue != value)
                {
                    RaiseListChangedEvents = false;

                    // If filter value is null, reset list.
                    if (value == null)
                    {
                        this.ClearItems();

                        foreach (T t in unfilteredListValue)
                            this.Items.Add(t);

                        filterValue = value;
                    }

                    // If the value is empty string, do nothing.
                    else if (value == "") { }

                    // If the value is not null or string, than process normal.
                    // Regex.Matches(value, "[?[\\w]+]? ?[=] ?'?[\\w|/: ]+'?", RegexOptions.Singleline)
                    else if (Regex.Matches(value, "[?[\\w]+]? ?[=] ?'?[\\w]+'?", RegexOptions.Singleline).Count == 0)
                    {
                        // If the filter is not set.
                        unfilteredListValue.Clear();
                        unfilteredListValue.AddRange(this.Items);
                        filterValue = value;
                        GetFilterParts();
                        ApplyFilter();
                    }
                    // Regex.Matches(value, "[?[\\w]+]? ?[=] ?'?[\\w|/: ]+'?", RegexOptions.Singleline)
                    else if (Regex.Matches(value, "[?[\\w]+]? ?[=] ?'?[\\w]+'?", RegexOptions.Singleline).Count > 1)
                    {
                        unfilteredListValue.Clear();
                        unfilteredListValue.AddRange(this.Items);
                        filterValue = value;
                        GetFilterEntries();
                    }
                    else
                        throw new ArgumentException("Filter is not in the format: propName = 'value'.");

                    RaiseListChangedEvents = true;
                    OnListChanged(new ListChangedEventArgs(ListChangedType.Reset, -1));
                }
            }
        }

        // If multiple filters were specified, separate the filter entries.
        // Incomplete: currently only handles AND. No handling of brackets, OR among others.
        public void GetFilterEntries()
        {
            string[] filterentries = Filter.Split(new string[] { "AND" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            int index = 0;

            foreach (string filter in filterentries)
            {
                string[] filterParts = filter.Split(new char[] { '=' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

                filterPropertyNameValues[index] = filterParts[0].Replace("[", "").Replace("]", "").Trim();

                PropertyDescriptor propDesc = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T))[filterPropertyNameValues[0].ToString()];

                if (propDesc != null)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        TypeConverter converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(propDesc.PropertyType);
                        filterCompareValues[index] = converter.ConvertFromString(filterParts[1].Replace("'", "").Trim());
                    }
                    catch (NotSupportedException)
                    {
                        throw new ArgumentException("Specified filter value " +
                          FilterCompare + " can not be converted from string. Implement a type converter for " + propDesc.PropertyType.ToString());
                    }
                }
                else throw new ArgumentException("Specified property '" + filterPropertyNameValues[0] + "' is not found on type " + typeof(T).Name + ".");
            }
        }

        // Parse the filter entry to it get the Property Name and Compare Value.
        public void GetFilterParts()

        {
            string[] filterParts = Filter.Split(new char[] { '=' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            filterPropertyNameValue = filterParts[0].Replace("[", "").Replace("]", "").Trim();

            PropertyDescriptor propDesc = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T))[filterPropertyNameValue.ToString()];

            if (propDesc != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    TypeConverter converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(propDesc.PropertyType);
                    filterCompareValue = converter.ConvertFromString(filterParts[1].Replace("'", "").Trim());
                }
                catch (NotSupportedException)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentException("Specified filter value " +
                      FilterCompare + " can not be converted from string. Implement a type converter for " +propDesc.PropertyType.ToString()) ;
                }
            }
            else throw new ArgumentException("Specified property '" + FilterPropertyName + "' is not found on type " + typeof(T).Name + ".");
        }

        // Applies the filter to the list, returning only entries that match the filter.
        // Need a new version of this to handle multiple filters.
        private void ApplyFilter()
        {
            unfilteredListValue.Clear();
            unfilteredListValue.AddRange(this.Items);

            List<T> results = new List<T>();

            PropertyDescriptor propDesc = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T))[FilterPropertyName];

            if (propDesc != null)
            {
                int tempResults = -1;

                do
                {
                    tempResults = FindCore(tempResults + 1, propDesc, FilterCompare);

                    if (tempResults != -1)
                        results.Add(this[tempResults]);

                } while (tempResults != -1);
            }

            this.ClearItems();

            if (results != null && results.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (T itemFound in results)
                    this.Add(itemFound);
            }
        }

        // Remove the filter.
        public void RemoveFilter()
        {
            if (Filter != null) Filter = null;
        }

        // Starts FindCore from startIndex 0 if no index was provided.
        protected override int FindCore(PropertyDescriptor prop, object key)
        {
            return FindCore(0, prop, key);
        }

        // Finds a List entry wher the Property value matches the compare value (key)
        protected int FindCore(int startIndex, PropertyDescriptor prop, object key)
        {
            // Get the property info for the specified property.
            PropertyInfo propInfo = typeof(T).GetProperty(prop.Name);

            T item;

            if (key != null)
            {
                // Loop through the items to see if the key value matches the property value.
                for (int i = startIndex; i < Count; ++i)
                {
                    item = (T)Items[i];
                    if (propInfo.GetValue(item, null).Equals(key))
                        return i;
                }
            }
            return -1;
        }

        // Required to implement IBindingListView, but not implemented here
        public ListSortDescriptionCollection SortDescriptions => throw new NotImplementedException();

        // Required to implement IBindingListView, but not implemented
        //public bool SupportsAdvancedSorting => throw new NotImplementedException();
        public bool SupportsAdvancedSorting
        {
            get { return false; }
        }

        // End of Class
    }

    // End of Namespace
}
```